# Alpine.js loading button with loading icon

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a button like this. It go disable when someone click on it, and text change from login to Please Wait ...

```
<button 
    id="import_btn" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-login w-100 mb-2" 
    type="submit" 
    x-data="{loading:false}" 
    x-on:click="loading=true; document.getElementById('form').submit();"
    x-text="loading ? 'Please Wait ...' : 'Login'" class="disabled:opacity-50" 
    x-bind:disabled="loading">
    <i class="uil uil-sign-in-alt"></i> Login
</button>
```

i did it with Alpine.js, and it work fine. now i want to add a loading icon like `(<i class="uil uil-loding"></i>)` with Please Wait ... text. how can i do it in Alpine.js?

Comment: Pay attention to your tags; `alpine` is for the Linux-based operating system, which states: "For questions related to the JS package, use alpine.js".

Answer (score 3):

In your example, when the click event fires, it is overwriting the icon element enclosed in the button element.
Instead of x-text, you can use x-html to inject both the text and the icon element into the button. Note the backticks so that you can use both single and double quotes for the x-html expression.

try this:

```
<button 
    id="import_btn" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-login w-100 mb-2" 
    type="submit" 
    x-data="{loading:false}"
    x-on:click="loading=true; document.getElementById('form').submit();"
    x-html="loading ? `<i class='uil uil-loding uil-sign-in-alt'></i> Please Wait ...` : 'Login'" class="disabled:opacity-50" 
    x-bind:disabled="loading">
    Login
</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your help it working fine, but loading showing in top of the button.  i want to show text and loading icon side by side in the button.

Comment: I updated the answer to see if it better suits your needs.